# bcp issues with the cmd running returning nothing

Tags: sql-server

I have a batch file but it is not running and giving me no error but doing nothing

```
bcp [AcademicDbo].[dbo].[AccCriteriaDummy] out c:\temp\csvdump\dbo_AccCriteriaDummy.csv -Usa -Pqwerty -C 65001 -t "|" -k -c -S localhost
```

[image]

it seems working but the problem I am having is:

> Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Warning: BCP import with a format file will convert empty strings in delimited columns to NULL.

I want to show along the headers and the data, but how can I get headers

I am not sure what is going wrong with it, but it should work.

Comment: It's not clear what your question is but BCP does not include column headings, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: Does this help? It's for `in` but it is the same mysterious behaviour - 0 rows copied. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16309826/bcp-returns-no-errors-but-also-doesnt-copy-any-rows

Comment: i made it work, it does work, but as mentioned by someone it will not copy the headers